# convert a string to a reg binary (utf8 array) in powershell

Tags: powershell, registry

I a trying to import a list of proxy exemptions from a file, and then write those imported values to two seperate locaions in tge registry. One is a `reg_sz` the other is `reg_binary`.

The reg_binary is the issue. I am getting errors converting the string to a utf8 value.

What I am running is as follows:

```
cls
# $encUnicode = [System.Text.Encoding]::UNICODE
$endUTF8 = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

$B = "H"

$POBS2 = $endUTF8.getstring($b)

write-host $POBS2
```

That generates this error:

```
Cannot convert argument "bytes", with value: "H", for "GetString" to type
"System.Byte[]": "Cannot convert value "H" to type "System.Byte[]". Error:
"Cannot convert value "H" to type "System.Byte".
Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."""
At C:\Temp\Foo.ps1:10 char:9
+         $POBS2 = $endUTF8.getstring($b)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvali
```

Answer (score 0):

That getstring() method is expecting a character array as input.

```
$endUTF8 = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

$B = [char[]]"H"

$POBS2 = $endUTF8.getstring($b)
```

Comment: That does solve the error he's getting, but ironically this corrected version of his code effectively does nothing for him. With this, and looking at his intent, he's loading strings from a file, converting those strings into  character arrays and then back into strings. I think what he really wants is to cast his string into a byte array or some such, so he probably really wants `$endUTF8.GetBytes($B)` in which case he doesn't need the character array.